# How to list files/directories in a repository?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I'd like to get all file/directorie's names underneath a repository by running a command. Are there any command line tool like `wget` to do this?

For example: the repository url is [repository](https://ruby.taobao.org/mirrors/ruby/)

I'd like to get a list of file/directorie's names

> 1.0/
>   1.1a/
>   1.1b/
>   1.1c/
>   1.1d/
>   1.2/
>   1.3/
>   1.4/
>   1.6/
>   1.8/
>   1.9/
>   2.0/
>   2.1/
>   2.2/
>   2.3/
>   2.4/                    binaries/               doc/                    stable/                 index.txt
>   ruby-1.8.5-p115.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.5-p115.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.5-p115.zip
>   ruby-1.8.6-p114.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.6-p114.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.6-p114.zip
>   ruby-1.8.6-p383.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.6-p383.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.6-p383.zip
>   ruby-1.8.6-p388.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.6-p388.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.6-p388.zip
>   ruby-1.8.6-p398.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.6-p398.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.6-p398.zip
>   ruby-1.8.6-p399.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.6-p399.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.6-p399.zip
>   ruby-1.8.6-p420.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.6-p420.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.6-p420.zip
>   ruby-1.8.7-p174.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.7-p174.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.7-p174.zip
>   ruby-1.8.7-p248.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.7-p248.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.7-p248.zip
>   ruby-1.8.7-p249.tar.bz2 ruby-1.8.7-p249.tar.gz  ruby-1.8.7-p249.zip
>   ...

Comment: give this line a try: `curl 'url'|grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<]+'`

Comment: Thanks a lot Kent, I am always informed about the usage about `grep` while setting -Po. I have no idea about it.

Comment: here I cannot access https in my terminal, so I put it in comment. if it worked, I would move it as an answer @Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wget` and filter the results:

```
wget -O - "https://ruby.taobao.org/mirrors/ruby/" | grep href | cut -d"\"" -f 2 > list.txt
```

Now `cat list.txt` will give:

```
../
1.0/
1.1a/
1.1b/
1.1c/
1.1d/
1.2/
1.3/
1.4/
1.6/
1.8/
1.9/
2.0/
2.1/
2.2/
2.3/
2.4/
binaries/
doc/
stable/
index.html
index.txt
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. One more question, how can I get these strings if the "href" attribute is absolute url, for example, href="https://ruby.taobao.org/mirrors/ruby/ruby-1.8.5-p115.tar.gz"

Comment: @Jeff you can look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70843/print-last-field-from-line-alternative-for-awk) for some methods to take the last field

Comment: Thank you, finally I have done this via sed expression. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing xml/html with regex is not a good idea. However it helps for a dirty and quick usage. Keep in mind that don't put this in your production codes.

With the regex, you can do more. After checking the HTML code, these lines should work for you:

```
curl 'url'|grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<]+'
```

or

```
curl 'url'|grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<]+(?=</a>)`
```

The 2nd one is gonna extract the KEY in  `<a href="foo">KEY</a>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kent, I fixed this finally.